# Android: Getting free space of an empty MediaStore storage/volume?

Tags: path, android, media, uri

I am trying to determine a free space of a MediaStore storage (an SD card - MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY in my case). The following code works OK:

```java
Uri videoContentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(volumeName);
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
try (Cursor cursor = resolver.query(videoContentUri, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}, null, null, null)) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int dataIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(dataIdx);
        StatFs statFs = new StatFs(filePath);
        long freeBytes = (statFs.getAvailableBlocksLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong());
        ...
    }
}
```

However, if the storage contains no items yet, the query returns an empty cursor, no filePath gets determined, and no file stats can be obtained. Please what is the direct way to obtain filePath for the MediaStore content "root", without querying any existing item? Or even more directly querying the MediaStore content for available space, without StatsFs involved, if possible.

P.S.: I am aware that the DATA field is deprecated, trying to find some way first. A most up-to-date method would be great, of course.